# Copy a file to all subfolders of a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i need to copy test.swf to all subfolders of c:/test folder's that doesn't contain "git" word

just tried something like that but not worked

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /r %%a in (.) do
( 
if not x%a:git=%==x%a% do
(
@copy "C:\test.swf" %a > nul
)
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just did it by vbscript

```
Const SourceDir = "C:\source"
Const TargetDir  = "C:\target\"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(TargetDir)
Set colSubfolders = objFolder.Subfolders

Set dosyalarklasor = objFSO.GetFolder(SourceDir)
Set dosyalar = dosyalarklasor.Files


For Each objSubfolder in colSubfolders
    if not instr(objSubfolder.Name,".git") > 0 then
        For Each dosya in dosyalar
        objFSO.CopyFile dosya, TargetDir & objSubfolder.Name & "\"
        Next
    end if 
Next
```

Comment: Hi, I found your code looking for something similar. You help me so much! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 5):

There is certainly nothing wrong with using vbscript :-) *(see [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11703970/1012053))*

But I thought I would point out where your batch code went wrong.

- The left paren must go on the same line as the IF or DO, and there must be a preceding space.
- DO is not used with IF
- You also need the FOR /D option to go along with /R. Without it you will get files instead of directories.
- Your `.` will include the parent directory. You want `*` instead to get just the children.
- I'm not sure about your requirement, but I assume a path like `C:\test\_git_\test` should get the file because the folder name does not contain "git" (though the parent does). Your code would look for git anywhere in the path.
- All FOR variables must be referenced with double percents as in %%a when in a batch file. You were not consistent.
- You cannot perform search and replace on a FOR variable, only on environment variables.

Additional points for improvement, though not errors:

- It is extremely rare that enableExtensions is needed. It is enabled by default.
- Better to put `@echo off` at the top then prefix each command with `@`.
- You enabled delayed expansion, but did not use it. Although a correct solution using your algorithm would require it.

Here is the correct code for your algorithm. *(actually none of the code solutions below have been tested, but I think I got them correct)*

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /d /r "c:\test" %%F in (*) do (
  set "name=%%~nxF"
  if "!name:git=!" neq "!name!" copy "c:\test.swf" "%%F" >nul
)
```

The above usually works. But it fails if a folder name contain `!` because delayed expansion would corrupt the expansion of %%F. The solution is to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /d /r "c:\test" %%F in (*) do (
  set "name=%%~nxF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if "!name:git=!" neq "!name!" (
    endlocal
    copy "c:\test.swf" "%%F" >nul
  ) else endlocal
)
```

But there is a much simpler method. You can pipe the results of DIR to FINDSTR with a regex that will filter out folders with "git" in the name. Then use FOR /F to process the results.
***Edit*** - *I simplified the regex.*

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /ad /s /b "c:\test\*" ^| findstr /virc:"git[^\\]*$"'
) do copy "c:\test.swf" "%%F"
```

The entire process can be done on one line from the command line

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /ad /s /b "c:\test\*" ^| findstr /virc:"git[^\\]*$"') do @copy "c:\test.swf" "%F"
```