# Recursively copy file to a directory all its sub-directory in command prompt

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy a single file for eg. C:\test.dll to all the sub folders present in C:\test\ folder, is there any way I can do this Using  windows batch script or do I have to use other scripting like python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy a file to all subfolders of a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703834/copy-a-file-to-all-subfolders-of-a-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d /r "c:\test\" %%a in (*) do copy c:\test.dll "%%~fa"
```

For each folder under c:\test copy the indicated file to the folder

Answer (score 0):

Reading python and modifying it are lots simpler than reading archaic batch commands.  Which is probably why you are asking the question in the first place.

```
import shutil
import os

for dir in os.listdir('c:\\test\\') if os.path.isdir(dir):
    shutil.copyfile('c:\\test.dll',dir)
```

Comment: Sometimes it is true but quite many times it is not. So if all you need is for files in directory and launch x then batch is much more readable. On the plus side its far more portable.

Answer (score -2):

```
for /R "C:\test\" %a in (*) do copy c:\test.dll "%~fa"
```